# Curl is not working after install, why?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 server and i have ran

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

and get output:

```
php-curl is already the newest version
```

when i run:

```
curl -V
```

i get:

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10
zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

in the phpinfo() page i dont see curl enabled/installed and when i run any curl function i got error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in ...
```

yesterday was working fine. i updated the php and now its not working any more...

Comment: Try to add your php version number when you install php_curl, something like `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl` or `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use curl u should enable it first.Find your `php.ini` file and uncomment this line.

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Don't forget to **restart the apache**..

```
 /opt/lampp/lampp service apache2 restart
```

Comment: And remember that apache needs to be restarted.

Comment: @Michael Forgot to mention it... thanks for reminding me

Comment: it dosent work for me. i did it. itsnt it that obly for windows, because dll because are for windows only...

Comment: please make sure that ur edit has been applied... u will need sudo permission to edit php.ini..... and dll are not for windows only

Answer (score 1):

the solution in my case was to install curl using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
```

thanks to @casimir-et-hippolyte